# HashMap<String, Student> searching for instance in Student class

Tags: search, hashmap

I am working with two helper classes (Student, Helper), as well as a main class.

In the Student class, I have the following constructor:

```
Student(String iName, String iMajor, int iNumber) {
    name = iName;
    major = iMajor;
    number = iNumber;
}
```

In the Helper class, I declare a HashMap as follows:

```
HashMap<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
```

Now, I have written a few method for adding (put) new students into the HashMap construction, as well as a method for retrieving information about a student based on the name.

```
//Adding new students
Student s1 = new Student("Alex", "Biology", 19);
Student s2 = new Student("Brian", "Chemistry", 20);
Student s3 = new Student("Tom", "Biology", 20);
//etc...

//Get student from name (key)
public Student getFromKey(String key) {
    return students.get(key);
}
```

I am now looking to write a method that finds all students based on either major or number. For instance, the call:

```
helper.getStudents("Biology");
```

Should return all the students studying Biology. I imagine the method looking something like:

```
public Student getStudents(String searchItem) {
    for(Students st : students.values()) {
        if(searchItem.equals(??)) {
            return st;
//Something like this.
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to access these values. All the classes have appropriate getter and setter methods, and the program works fine. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this `Map` exists:

```
HashMap<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
```

The following would work:

```
   public Student getStudents(String searchItem) {
    for(Map.Entry<String,Student> entry : students.entrySet()) {
        Student student = entry.getValue();
        //perform conditional logic here
    }
```

Here is a more complete example in case you need it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Student {

private String name;
private String major;
private int number;

public Student(String name, String major, int number) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.major = major;
    this.number = number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Joe", "Jack", "John","James");
    List<String> majors = Arrays.asList("English","Math","Geography");
    Map<String,Student> students = new HashMap<String,Student>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        Collections.shuffle(names);
        Collections.shuffle(majors);
        students.put(names.get(0) + String.valueOf(i), new Student(names.get(0), majors.get(0), i));
}

    List<Student> mathMajors = getStudents(students, "Math");
    for(Student student:mathMajors){
        System.out.println(student.name);
        System.out.println(student.major);
    }
}

public static List<Student> getStudents(Map<String,Student> students, String searchToken){
    List<Student> results = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for(Entry<String,Student> entry:students.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue().getMajor().equalsIgnoreCase(searchToken)){
        results.add(entry.getValue());
    }
}
return results;
}

public String getName() {
return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getMajor() {
return this.major;
}

public void setMajor(String major) {
this.major = major;
}

public int getNumber() {
return this.number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
this.number = number;
}

}
```

[On Github](https://gist.github.com/kmb385/7786170)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked very well. 
What exactly does the Map.Entry<String, Student> declaration do?

Comment: The for loop is using the `for..each` syntax, so for every entry in the map which is of type `Map.Entry<String,Student>` it will iterate.  Prior to the iteration, it stores the entry for the iteration into the `entry` variable which is of type `Map.Entry<String,Student>`.